# Pattern matching в scala

Tags: scala

Есть такой класс:

```
case class Sex(name: String, number: Int)

object Sex {

  val FEMALE = new Sex("FEMALE", 1)
  val MALE = new Sex("MALE", 2)

  def apply(number: Int): Sex = number match {
    case FEMALE.number => FEMALE
    case MALE.number => MALE
  }
}
```

Меня очень беспокоит метод `apply`, как его модифицировать, чтобы не писать однотипных конструкций?

Comment: Оно ведь даже не компилиться. Может тебе лучше добавить их в коллекцию, например в Map,  и доставать по ключу?

Comment: Да, согласен, этот код еще в добавок и не компилируется. Хорошо. Я думал, что на объектах FEMALE и MALE в методе apply будет вызываться unapply, который возвратит значение типа Int. Тогда как, мне явно, не задавая number, реализовать метод unapply, который бы, возвращал FEMALE или MALE?

Comment: т.е. я не хочу при изменении номера у объекта, изменять его еще и в методе unapply

Comment: Вынести в коллекцию типо такого - https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WQrqYgG/0
Либо юзать Enumeration (правда индекс с нуля) - https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WQrqYgG/1

Comment: @EnverOsmanov с коллекцией это не круто совсем. А в варианте с Enumeration есть возможность запихнуть дополнительные поля?

Comment: "с коллекцией это не круто" - в чем не крутость проявляется? Если не get-ать, а возвращать Option, то это один из самых безопасных вариантов получается - не схлопочешь исключение в рантайме если кто-то вздумает дать методу apply не тот индекс. Еще безопасней делать отдельные классы Female и Male наследниками sealed трейта Sex. Тогда проверка будет на этапе компиляции. Но выбирать надо по ситуации конечно.
У Enumeration можно переопределить имя и индекс.
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/WQrqYgG/2

Comment: Не крутость проявляется в создании дополнительной сущности, помимо самих объектов

Comment: Пожалуй, с Enumeration вариант интересный. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не пользуюсь Enumeration, не понимаю чем не устраивает создать sealed trait iSex { def id: Int } и создать объекты object Female { val id = 1} extends iSex и object Male { val id = 2 } extends iSex. Это более verbose но работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой и схожих ситуаций существует библиотека [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum)

Вот как мог бы выглядеть код с использованием enumeratum:

```
import enumeratum.values.{IntEnum, IntEnumEntry}

sealed abstract class Sex(val name: String, val value: Int) extends IntEnumEntry

object Sex extends IntEnum[Sex]{
  def values: IndexedSeq[Sex] = findValues
  case object Female extends Sex("FEMALE", 1)
  case object Male extends Sex("MALE", 2)
}
```

Основные преимущества по сравнению со встренным `Enumeration` составляют:

1. Позволяет абстрактному типу перечисляемых значением быть полноценным `trait\class` с методами, значениями, внутренними типами и т.п.
2. Составление мэппинга имён (для `Enum`) или других ключей (для `ValueEnum`) cо значениями на этапе компиляции
3. Проверка уникальности ключей для `ValueEnum` на этапе компиляции. К примеру в вышеприведённом коде если изменить строку определения `Male` на

   ```
   case object Male extends Sex("MALE", 1)
   ```

   компилятор пожалуется на неуникальные значения
4. [Производительность](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum#benchmarking). Особенный прирост заметен для случаев, когда для имени может быть не определено перечисляемого значения, стандартная реализация выбрасывает `NuSuchElementException`, в то время как в `enumeratum.Enum` определён метод `withNameOption` со значительно более низкими накладными расходами.
5. Вспомогательные методы для поиска по имени в верхнем регистре, нижнем регистре и без учёта регистра
6. Интеграция с популярными JSON библиотеками

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что в тех случаях, когда решение ситуации одним средством языка неестественно, следует использовать другое средство. Например, перечисление:

```
object Sex extends Enumeration {
  val Male, Female = Value
}
```